# Reading a .json file in Python not knowing in advance whether it is enclosed in square brackets [ ]

Tags: python, json

I have a `.json` file that looks like this:

```
{
"aaa":"xxx"
"bbb":"yyy"
},
{
"ccc":"zzz"
"ddd":"qqq"
}
```

I don’t know in advance how many sets of curly braces `{ }` are in the file (items). Might be 0, 1 or any other natural number.
I also don't know whether the whole file is enclosed in square brackets `[ ]` or not.
I want to read it as a list of dictionaries, so I use the following:

```
      try:
        pvt = json.loads(data)
      except:
        pvt = json.loads("["+data+"]")
```

This solution works if I have more than one item if the file is not enclosed into square brackets `[ ]` or with any number or items if is is enclosed. The only case when it fails i.e. it is read as `dict` instead of `list` is when I don't have square brackets `[ ]` and have only one item in the file.

Could you suggest me the solution to read my file as a list of dictionaries in any case?

Thank you!

Comment: That is **not a JSON file** since it isn't in a valid JSON format. The fundamental solution to your problem is to fix whatever the source of this file is to make it produce a valid JSON.

Answer (score 0):

What about this?

```
def fix_my_json(json_string):

    if len(json_string) == 0 or (json_string[0] != "[" and json_string[-1] != "]"):
        return "["+json_string+"]"

    return json_string
```

and then you can do

```
pvt = json.loads(fix_my_json(data))
```

Answer (score 0):

When parsing, you could simply assume that the file content is not surrounded by brackets and flatten the resulting list if necessary:

```py
pvt = json.loads("[" + data + "]")
if len(pvt) > 0 and type(pvt[0]) == list:
    # if the file content was already a list, i. e. surrounded by brackets
    pvt = pvt[0]
```